# Document set workflow, access column of document set content type

Tags: document-set

I have configured a workflow on document set library, each document set has a "Status" column. when user uploads a new document in the document set, a workflow triggers and I want to access the status column (which is in document set content type) in my current workflow. workflow is triggered by the document being uploaded how can I access the the column in document set that contains the current document?

Comment: Any resuts on your question yet? I have the same issue

Comment: Only you replied so far :)